# Topic: How to change the pricing field labels?

Tags: php, virtuemart, cart

Joomla 1.7.3/VM 2.0.0

Hi, I want to change the pricing labels slightly. So for 'Sales Price'. I would like to simply use 'Price'. I've searched everywhere but can't work out how to do this. Are these stored in the db somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can change " Sales price " label from language file

open language/en-GB/en-GB.com_virtuemart.ini file

find COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_SALESPRICE="Sales price: "

and change "Sales price: "